# Как вставить данные в определенный элемент в xml файл

Tags: c#, xml

Есть файл resources.xml и в него нужно заносить данные. Вот например пытаюсь вставить элемент `video` с аттрибутом `name`=qwetyuui. Вот исходный файл resources.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <texts>
        <text name="text_barabann_scanner">
        <content> Барабанные сканеры обеспечивают наивысшее раз¬решение сканирования, но они предназначены в ос¬новном для сканирования не бумажных документов, а прозрачных материалов, например слайдов, нега-тивов и т.п. В сканерах этого типа считывающая го¬ловка устанавливается неподвижно, а изображение, закрепленное на цилиндрическом барабане, враща¬ется с высокой скоростью и сканируется построчно.</content>
    </text>
    </texts>
    <videos> 
    <video name="video_planshet_scaner">
        <path>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNLZ1f-nD5c</path>
    </video>
</videos>
</resources>
```

Вот файл после добавления в него информации:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
    <texts>
      <text name="text_barabann_scanner">
        <content> Барабанные сканеры обеспечивают наивысшее раз¬решение сканирования, но они предназначены в ос¬новном для сканирования не бумажных документов, а прозрачных материалов, например слайдов, нега-тивов и т.п. В сканерах этого типа считывающая го¬ловка устанавливается неподвижно, а изображение, закрепленное на цилиндрическом барабане, враща¬ется с высокой скоростью и сканируется построчно.</content>
      </text>
    </texts>

    <videos>
      <video name="video_planshet_scaner">
        <path>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNLZ1f-nD5c</path>
      </video>
    </videos>
    <videos />
    <video name="qwertyuui">
      <path>wqedasda</path>
    </video>
    <videos />
    <video name="">
      <path></path>
    </video>    
  </resources>
```

То есть мне например нужно добавить элемент типа video в элемент videos, но оно как-то криво добавляется. Вот код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string TextNameValue = "";
        string VideoNameValue = "";
        string TextContent = "";
        string VideoPath = "";
        //HttpWebRequest qwe = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://vws.vuforia.com/targets");
        //qwe.Method = "GET";

        //PostNewTarget postNewTarget = new PostNewTarget();
        //postNewTarget.setHeaders(qwe);
        Console.WriteLine("How count elements you want add? ");
        int count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please chose type object: 1. Video. 2.Text;");
            string type = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (type)
            {
                case "Video":
                    Console.WriteLine("Input name: ");
                    string vname = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Input path: ");
                    string vpath = Console.ReadLine();
                    XDocument xVideoDoc = XDocument.Load("resources.xml");
                    xVideoDoc.Root.Add(new XElement("videos"),new 
        XElement("video",
                        new XAttribute("name", VideoNameValue),
                        new XElement("path", VideoPath)));
                    xVideoDoc.Save("resources.xml");
                    break;
                case "Text":
                    Console.WriteLine("Input name: ");
                    string tname = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Input content: ");
                    string tcontent = Console.ReadLine();
                    XDocument xTextDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("texts", 
 new XElement("text", new XAttribute("name", tname),
    new XElement("content", tcontent))));
                    xTextDoc.Save("resources.xml");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect input!");
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Вы в цикле создаёте root элемент. Поэтому так получается

Comment: Так вы не в Root добавляйте, а в videos. Создайте videos: `var videos = new XElement("videos")`, добавьте все video в него с помощью Add, а потом добавьте уже videos в Root

Comment: @АндрейNOP сделал. Но добавление идет не в сам элемент videos, а после него создает еще элемент videos и в него заносится, вот например:
  <videos>
    <video name="qszcx">
      <path>cdsdc</path>
    </video>
  </videos>
  <videos>
    <video name="video_computer">
      <path>assets/unity/resources</path>
    </video>
  </videos> Так же вроде не должно быть